# Green feather-like formations in tap water - what is it? (with pictures)

Tags: zoology, botany, species-identification

These things recently appeared in my tap water Copenhagen Denmark, this summer 2013. They are very small, and have a feather like structure. I've called the water supply, and they thought that it was some tracer put in there by humans to trace if the warm water supply leaks into the tap water. But I could not show them the pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What are they? Are they dangerous?

For size comparison: the green stuff is located on the top right of a piece of A4 paper.

Comment: Some sort of algae? You might need (somehow) an even closer picture to get a good identification.

Comment: I'm also thinking algae or moss (overall apperance could match species in Dicranaceae?). Better picture probably needed though. Would be strange for something like a moss to find its way through your tap water supply though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a biologist out taking some samples of the water. She examined them in a microscope, and identified the algae as blue-green algae/cyanobacteria. She could not identify the species further.

She said the reason probably was that my pipes where exposed to sunlight, and also that the pibes with hot and cold water ran too close to each other, creating a nice lukewarm temperature for the algae to thrive in.

I'm of course going to change the pipes :)

[image: The pictures shows my water pipes being exposed to sunlight creating an environment in which the algae can grow]